How to Minimize Delay in Twilio's Speech Recognition Gather Action Response?
I am developing a speech recognition system using Twilio and a Node.js application. The goal is to play an audio clip immediately after the user stops speaking during a call.
Twilio Calls Logs
However, I am experiencing a significant delay of about 4-5 seconds between when the user stops speaking and when Twilio invokes the Gather action URL to process the speech recognition result. This delay is recorded in Twilio’s logs and is significantly affecting the responsiveness of my application.
Expected Behavior: The action URL should be triggered immediately after the user stops speaking.
What I Have Tried:

Adjusting speechTimeout: Used speechTimeout: 'auto' and other values to detect end of speech promptly.
Analyzing Logs: Verified that the delay is not due to server-side processing but within Twilio.
Reviewing Documentation: Checked Twilio’s Gather documentation for optimizations.
Exploring Similar Issues: Referenced related issues but found no direct solution for the delay


Reducing silence waiting time in Twilio speech recognition
Twilio gather delay in speech-to-text processing
Delay in Twilio outbound voice calls

app.post('/voice-response', (req, res) => {
  logWithTimestamp('Handling voice response');

  const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  // Gather speech input with a timeout
  twiml.gather({
    input: ['speech'],
    action: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/gather`, // This URL handles the gathered speech
    speechTimeout: '1', // Automatically detect when speech has ended
    // enhanced: true,
    speechModel: "experimental_conversations",
  });

  // If no input is received, play a message
  twiml.say('You need to say something');

  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
  logWithTimestamp('Sent TwiML response for gathering speech');
});

// Endpoint to handle the gather action response
app.post('/gather', (req, res) => {
  logWithTimestamp(`Incoming Gather Request: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);

  const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  if (req.body.SpeechResult) {
    logWithTimestamp(`Speech detected: ${req.body.SpeechResult}`);
    // If speech is detected, acknowledge the speech
    twiml.play(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/voice/output.mp3`);
  } else {
    logWithTimestamp('No speech detected, playing default message');
    // If no speech is detected, play an audio message
    twiml.say('You need to say something');
  }

  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
  logWithTimestamp('Sent TwiML response for gather action');
});

